# Collisions without physics

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the simplest platformer prototype with the simplest physics (falling with gravity, moving left and right, and (maybe) jump). For example:

```
void Move () {
   if (!isDying || !isDead || !isShooting || !isFalling)
   {
     float amountToMove = Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed;
     transform.Translate(Vector3.right * amountToMove);
   }
}

void ApplyGravity() {

   float amountToMove = Time.deltaTime * gravity;
   transform.Translate(Vector3.down * amountToMove);

}
```

The problem is i don't know how to make collisions without physics and with isKinematic enabled. The only thing i know is to use a OnTriggerEnter function, so added a isTrigger to all objects and wrote (Hero.cs):

```
 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider otherGameObjectCollider) {
   if (otherGameObjectCollider.gameObject.tag == "ground") {
     Debug.Log("ground/wall collision");
   }
}
```

I know that i need stop my hero to prevent falling (walking) through the ground but i really can't think it out.

Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isFalling` flag of your hero to determine whether he is in a falling. Try like this:

```
void ApplyGravity() {
   if (isFalling) {
     float amountToMove = Time.deltaTime * gravity;
     transform.Translate(Vector3.down * amountToMove);
   }
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider otherGameObjectCollider) {
   if (otherGameObjectCollider.gameObject.tag == "ground") {
     Debug.Log("ground/wall collision");
     isFalling = false;
   }
}
```

And when your hero leave the platform and not in a jumping, you should set the `isFalling` to true to make he begin to fall.

Maybe you'd like try to see the Unity officail demo: [3D Platformer Tutorial](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/5087). I believe it contains all trick and method you will need to build your platform game. Good luck. : )